# Implementing tags functionality with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to be able to tag any entity the easiest way possible. I have 2 entities (books and author)

```
public class Book : AbstractTag
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    public Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author : AbstractTag
{
    [Key]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

They both inherited from AbstractTag

```
public class AbstractTag : ITaggable
{
    public AbstractTag()
    {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

that can be taggable. I don't want dupplicate tags.

Here is my tag entity:

```
public class Tag
{
    public Tag()
    {
        Books = new List<Book>();
        Authors = new List<Author>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}

public interface ITaggable
{
    ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code I use to attach the tag to the entity:

```
public interface ITagService
{
    TEntity Tag<TEntity>(TEntity entity, string str) where TEntity : ITaggable;
    TEntity Untag<TEntity>(TEntity entity, string str) where TEntity : ITaggable;
}

public class TagService : ITagService
{
    private readonly Context _context = new Context();

    public TagService()
    {
    }

    public TagService(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public TEntity Tag<TEntity>(TEntity entity, string str) where TEntity : ITaggable
    {
        string tag = str.Trim();

        if (entity.Tags.All(t => t.Label != tag))
        {
            Tag t = _context.Tags.Add(new Tag {Label = tag});
            entity.Tags.Add(t);
        }

        return entity;
    }

    public TEntity Untag<TEntity>(TEntity entity, string str) where TEntity : ITaggable
    {
        Tag tag = entity.Tags.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Label == str);

        if (tag != null)
            entity.Tags.Remove(tag);

        return entity;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having, is that it creates duplicates and I don't understand why since the DB tables are weel generated. Obviously my code is wrong but I can't figure out why and where.

```
var context = new Context();

        var author = new Author {FirstName = "Stephen", LastName = "King"};
        var book = context.Books.Add(new Book
            {
                Title = "Title",
                Author = author,
                Genre = "Sci-Fi"
            });

        var service = new TagService(context);
        service.Tag(book, "best");
        service.Tag(author, "best");

        context.SaveChanges();
```

So when I execute that code, I only want 1 tag which should be 'best'. Instead I have 2 tags, both 'best'. Can anyone explain why, and how can I fix that issue

**UPDATE**
Here is what EF generates:

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Books",
            c => new
                {
                    BookId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Title = c.String(),
                    Genre = c.String(),
                    Author_AuthorId = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.BookId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Authors", t => t.Author_AuthorId)
            .Index(t => t.Author_AuthorId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Authors",
            c => new
                {
                    AuthorId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    FirstName = c.String(),
                    LastName = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.AuthorId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Tags",
            c => new
                {
                    TagId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Label = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.TagId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.TagBooks",
            c => new
                {
                    Tag_TagId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Book_BookId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Tag_TagId, t.Book_BookId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Tags", t => t.Tag_TagId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Books", t => t.Book_BookId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Tag_TagId)
            .Index(t => t.Book_BookId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.TagAuthors",
            c => new
                {
                    Tag_TagId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Author_AuthorId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Tag_TagId, t.Author_AuthorId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Tags", t => t.Tag_TagId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Authors", t => t.Author_AuthorId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Tag_TagId)
            .Index(t => t.Author_AuthorId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.TagAuthors", new[] { "Author_AuthorId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.TagAuthors", new[] { "Tag_TagId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.TagBooks", new[] { "Book_BookId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.TagBooks", new[] { "Tag_TagId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Books", new[] { "Author_AuthorId" });
        DropForeignKey("dbo.TagAuthors", "Author_AuthorId", "dbo.Authors");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.TagAuthors", "Tag_TagId", "dbo.Tags");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.TagBooks", "Book_BookId", "dbo.Books");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.TagBooks", "Tag_TagId", "dbo.Tags");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Books", "Author_AuthorId", "dbo.Authors");
        DropTable("dbo.TagAuthors");
        DropTable("dbo.TagBooks");
        DropTable("dbo.Tags");
        DropTable("dbo.Authors");
        DropTable("dbo.Books");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the same Tag entity, just the tag content. In Tag method you always create new entity which will have new TagId. You have to add additional check with given label if tag exsists and use that entity instead of creating new. For example:

```
if (entity.Tags.All(t => t.Label != tag))
{
    var tagEntity = _context.Tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Label == tag);

    if(tagEntity == null)
        tagEntity = _context.Tags.Add(new Tag {Label = tag});
    entity.Tags.Add(tagEntity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it still create 2 tags instead of 1. It looks lik a tag is bound to the entity in a way

Comment: It's weird because that additional check should be enough. Could you post database schema generated by EF?

Comment: You have to take a look into connectionString group in app.config or web.config (depends on application type) and you will find the database. Then use server explorer and check how the database has been generated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. I've enable the migrations, so I can grab what EF generates

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed your latest update of the post. It looks as I expected - correct.

Comment: I can re-run the script multiple times, it won't create more than those 2 tags. But 1 tag 'best' is strictly bound to the author table, and the other 'best' tag is strictly bound the book table.

Comment: I know where is the problem. I forgot that you call SaveChanges after all operations. When you call Tag method second time you still don't have Tag in your database so FirstOrDefault which I mentioned returns null.

Comment: But doesn't those entities lives in memory ? So it should be no problem I guess

Comment: Of course they live, but I'm not 100% sure if FirstOrDefault checks the memory as well.

Comment: That was the issue, not sure how to fix that when I use the repository pattern and fire the SaveChanges() at the end and not every time I attach a tag to an entity

Comment: If you don't want to call SaveChanges for a particular Tag then the only idea I have is something like in-memory dump of Tags and double check inside Tag method. That cache should be cleared after saving new records into db.